# www ServerAlias not working Apache2

Tags: linux, apache, tornado

I am trying to set up my tornado web application to run behind Apache2. The application listens on port 8888, and I am trying to get Apache to forward HTTP requests for the specified domain to this port. Here is my config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/

    ErrorLog /var/log/domain.error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/domain.log combined
    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

Navigating to domain.com works, but if I try to navigate to www.domain.com, I get Error code: ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not an error in your appache server but an **DNS problem** The subdomain "www" is not known/can not be resolved.

do be absolutly sure try a ping www.domain.com which will give you an unknown host, whereas a ping domain.com will be fine. To resolve it create an A record for the subdomain in your nameserver.i

Comment: I had the same issue adding Let's encrypt  to a  digital ocean laravel app.what I did was to add Cname record and it was resolved.